Как отловить кнопку в html?
День добрый! Есть вопрос! Учусь автотестам. Есть задание - протестировать Стим логин
Тестирую Python, Pytest, Selenium. Проблема с кнопкой "Войти". При вводе неправильного логина и нажатии "Войти", у кнопки исчезает надпись, появляется кружок загрузки, потом когда проверка не проходит - снова появляется текст "Войти." Мне нужно отловить состояние загрузки в ней. Но суть в том что когда кнопка меняется - у нее меняется только class, а он автогенерируемый => xpath-ом такое выбирать нельзя, потому что нестабильный локатор будет. Больше ничего не меняется, станица не перезагружается при нажатии, короче вообще никак, даже к надписи на кнопке нельзя прицепиться, потому что хоть она и исчезает вроде как, в самом теге она остается.
Подскажите, может есть еще какие способы отловить состояние загрузки у кнопки?

Проблема возникает с получением элемента кнопки или с определением находится она в состоянии загрузки или нет?
